# JQuery.i18n replaces none existing key with the key name instead of the fallback text

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, wikimedia

I am referring to https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n#data-api in the JQuery.i18n documentation:

```
<li data-i18n="message-key">Fallback text</li>
```

> It is also possible to have the above li node with fallback text
> already in place.

Unfortunately I don't get this work. When I don't have `message-key` in the language file then JQuery.i18n displays instead of `Fallback text` the key: `message-key`

**My question**:

What am I doing wrong? As soon I add the key to the language file then it gets replaced, so apparently the language file is loaded correctly and also the function calls seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug! I was checking the JQuery.i18n code and I found the problem.

It's all in `jquery.i18n.js`. It starts with this code in line #169:

```
if ( message === '' ) {
   message = key;
}
```

The `if` is executed when there is no text defined for the key and then the message *becomes* the key.

I commented the assignment:

```
if ( message === '' ) {
   // message = key;
}
```

---

Then I had to change in line #244 this code:

```
} else {
   $this.text( i18n.parse( messageKey ) );
}
```

to

```
} else {
   const translatedText = i18n.parse( messageKey );
   if ( '' !== translatedText ) {
      $this.text( translatedText  );
   }
}
```

---

Now the fallback text does work. The following comment in line number 165 seems to confirm it's a bug and the developer knows it but somehow he lives with it:

```
        // FIXME: This changes the state of the I18N object,
        // should probably not change the 'this.parser' but just
        // pass it to the parser.
```

---

If you apply this hack so consider also the modifications for `html` and other `tags` few lines above.